# Do repeated reads of the same storage value add to the total weight?

Tags: pallet, storage, frame, weight

I have an extrinsic with multiple calls to other pallet functions. As it calls other internal functions, more than one of them access the same storage value (either an actual `StorageValue` or the same key in a `StorageMap`).

Will this add to the total weight of the extrinsic, i.e., is there an additional cost to reading a storage value more than once? Should I refactor my code to read the storage value once and pass it around to avoid re-reading it?

Comment: Not sure how the cache works, but my practice is to minimize the read and write operations and count all of them.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that if your reading the same value multiple times in the same transaction then the read should be cached and you only pay for it once in weight. I think the same is true if you write to the same location multiple times in a transaction - it would only save the last write (and only charge you for one write).

Comment: That's interesting. Is there a way I can test that (e.g., with multiple reads) to make sure?

Comment: Maybe, the simplest way to test is to benchmark it, and do a A/B test, such as just add another 10 times call to read the same storage(and key), and check the benchmark value.

Comment: I don't think there's "pay" or "charge" in an extrinsic at all. All you can do is to benchmark the extrinsic, and assign a value to the weight for it. Depends on if you enable the state cache or not, you may get different benchmark result.